# Masking Image With Hollow Circle Shape & Blur

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, svg, react-native-svg

I'm trying to create the below crude example using react-native-svg.

The background image is dynamic and requires a hollow circular mask. This also needs to blur that section of the background image. Whilst I can get a cutout blurred with no problem, I cannot figure out how to create it exactly like the hollow one below. Advice appreciated.

[image: hollow circle cutout]

**Code Example:**

```
  <ImageBackground
    resizeMode="cover"
    source={{ uri: route.params?.image }}
    style={{ flex: 1}}
    blurRadius={0}
  >
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Svg width={300} height={300}>
        <Circle cx={150} cy={150} r={120} fill={"transparent"} />
        <Circle
          cx={150}
          cy={150}
          r={120}
          strokeWidth={60}
          stroke={hexToRgba("#000", "0.4")}
          fill="transparent"
        />
      </Svg>
    </View>
  </ImageBackground>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Have you made any attempts to to do this? What (relevant) "*[mcve]*" HTML and CSS have you written so far? If you share your code then we can make suggestions, otherwise - with just a picture - we can't really offer anything without making profound, and probably incorrect, guesses.

Comment: @DavidThomas Indeed, I downed tools in despair and in search of a warm libation, clarity is returning. I've included up to where I'm stuck. I'm in search now of how to blur the image in the Circle stroke, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a blurred version of the image on top of the image itself and add a mask to the blurred image with a circle.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 256 171" width="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blur1">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" />
    </filter>
    <mask id="m1">
      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="28%" stroke="white" stroke-width="13%" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <image id="img" width="100%" href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/36/Hopetoun_falls.jpg/512px-Hopetoun_falls.jpg" >
    <title>Photo by DAVID ILIFF, CC BY-SA 3.0 &lt;https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0&gt;, via Wikimedia Commons</title>
  </image>
  <use href="#img" filter="url(#blur1)" mask="url(#m1)"/>
</svg>
```

### Update

I don't know react-native-svg, but I guess you can use their converter [SVGR Playground - SVGR](https://react-svgr.com/playground/). It returns the following code that includes the filter:

```
import * as React from "react"
const SvgComponent = (props) => (
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width={400}
    viewBox="0 0 256 171"
    {...props}
  >
    <defs>
      <filter id="b">
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation={2} />
      </filter>
      <mask id="c">
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="28%" stroke="#fff" strokeWidth="13%" />
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <image
      id="a"
      width="100%"
      href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/36/Hopetoun_falls.jpg/512px-Hopetoun_falls.jpg"
    >
      <title>
        {
          "Photo by DAVID ILIFF, CC BY-SA 3.0 <https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0>, via Wikimedia Commons"
        }
      </title>
    </image>
    <use filter="url(#b)" href="#a" mask="url(#c)" />
  </svg>
)
export default SvgComponent
```

Comment: thank you, I'm using react-native-svg and I don't think feGaussianBlur is a thing currently

Comment: @wbdlc ok, but you need it to blur. I updated my answer. I don't know if that is useful?

Comment: Your answer is very helpful and clever, I'm checking on the implementation now. Thank you

Comment: Ah, when I select React Native, it drops support for filter

Comment: React native doesn't support SVG filters last I checked